# IF-Else condition in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

[image]Based on the status which displays whether appointment is available or  unavailable. I want to display if the status is available  the user will redirected through a link to new page and if appointment is unavailable the  status will be hidden. Not sure where I am going wrong..

```
</thead>
          <tbody>
          <?php
          if(is_array($appointmentdetails) || isset($displayAppointment)){
          foreach($appointmentdetails as $displayAppointment) { ?> 


          <tr>

            <td><?php print $displayAppointment['DOCTOR_LICENSE_NO']; ?></td>
            <td><?php print $displayAppointment['DOCTOR_FNAME']; ?></td>
            <td><?php print $displayAppointment['DOCTOR_LNAME']; ?></td>
            <td><?php print $displayAppointment['DOCTOR_EMAIL_ID']; ?></td>
            <td><?php print $displayAppointment['DOCTOR_PHONE']; ?></td>
            <td><?php print $displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_DATE']; ?></td>
            <td><?php print $displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_TIME']; ?></td>


   --> Here I want to display the given condition 

   <?php if($displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']=="Available")

                        { ?>    
                            <td><a href="input_user.php?APPOINTMENT_STATUS=<?php print $displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']; ?>"><?php print $displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']; ?></a></td>
                        <?php } 
                         else ?>
                        <?php {?>
                            <td><?php print $displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']; ?></td>
                        <?php}?>

      </tr>
      <?php } } ?>
                        </tbody>
      </table>

        </body>
```

Comment: This `'APPOINTMENT_STATUS'=="Available"` in comparing the two strings, not variables so it will always be false because `APPOINTMENT_STATUS` does not equal `Available`. You probably want to be comparing `$displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']` I'd guess..

Comment: it still gives the same error

Comment: What error? Theres no error mentioned in your question.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\EasyMed\access_form.php on line 111

Comment: Should have put that in your question. Look at `)
        echo 'APPOINTMENT_STATUS';
                            { `

Answer (score 1):

Create a field in the database/or the list as appointment status, if a appointment is available then make it true else false.
and use it in if else statement

```
if($displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS'])
{
   echo "Appointment available" ; //or what ever your link
}
else
{
   echo "redirect";
}
```

Comment: if the status is available the link should be enabled else status should be disabled. So, basically it is dependent on what appoint status is

Comment: in my table the column APPOINTMENT_STATUS contains two type of status Available and Unavailable. So, based on query if the column shows Available the link should get enabled else if the status is Unavailable the link gets disablled

Comment: `if($displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS'] == "Available")
{
   echo "Appointment available" ; //or what ever your link
}
else
{
   echo "Sorry appointment not available";
}`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\EasyMed\access_form.php on line 111

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110784/discussion-between-naresh-kumar-and-shweta).

Comment: <?php if($displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']=="Available")
      
                            { ?>    
                                <td><a href="input_user.php?APPOINTMENT_STATUS=<?php print $displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']; ?>"><?php print $displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']; ?></a></td>
                            <?php } 
                             else ?>
                            <?php {?>
                                <td><?php print $displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']; ?></td>
                            <?php}?>
          </tr>
          <?php } } ?>

Comment: <?php

if ($displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS'] == "Available")
 { ?> <td><a href="input_user.php?APPOINTMENT_STATUS=<?php
 echo $displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']; ?>"><?php
 echo $displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']; ?></a></td> <?php
 }
  else 

 { ?> <td> <?php
 echo $displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']; ?></td> <?php
 php
 } ?> </tr>

Answer (score 0):

In the php code, you put statement echo before you opened the if braces. Also in the if statement, it should be $displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']

```
<?php if($displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']=="Available")
   { 
  //put echo here
    echo 'APPOINTMENT_STATUS'; ?>
    <td><a href="input_user.php?APPOINTMENT_STATUS=<?php print $displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']; ?>"><?php print $displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']; ?></a></td>
     <?php } 
     else {?>
         <td> <input type="hidden" name="APPOINTMENT_STATUS" value="<?php print $displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS'];?>" ></td>
     <?php}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is Youre Code :
<td><?php print $displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']; ?></td>
                            <?php}?>

Need space after <?php 
Right Code :

 <td><?php print $displayAppointment['APPOINTMENT_STATUS']; ?></td>
                        <?php }?>
```